# Do I need a VM instance for each WordPress instance on Google Cloud?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, web-hosting, bitnami

I've been playing with Google Cloud, trying to figure out the most cost-effective way to host multiple low-traffic WordPress websites.

With **Bitnami**, it seems to me that for every new WordPress instance, I'm having to provision a new virtual machine. I also tried Google **click-to-deploy** WordPress setup, and it forced me to provision a cluster with 3 VM's.

Each of the new VM's cost money, so I'm wondering if there's a way to do something similar to shared Linux hosting, where I could host multiple WordPress instances on a single Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you don't want to use the Bitnami Multisite solution, you can also install multiple WordPress apps in the same server without installing multiple database or web servers. Bitnami provides modules to install on top of an installed stack (normally LAMP stack) and the WordPress module allows you set the name of the blog you want to create.

The module can be downloaded from [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/modules) but you will need to run the following commands in the instance (these commands will download the current version)

```
wget https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/269995/bitnami-wordpress-4.9.8-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run
chmod a+x bitnami-wordpress-4.9.8-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run
sudo ./bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-linux-x64-installer.run --wordpress_instance_name NEW_BLOG_NAME
```

Once you have the module installed, you will be able to access it through http://localhost/NEW_BLOG_NAME.

More info in the Bitnami documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/configuration/install-several-wordpress-modules/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Bitnami [Wordpress multisite](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress-multisite) stack, which allows multiple sites to run on one server.

Comment: Though that is one of the options I considered, I would prefer to have multiple instances of WordPress to a single multi-site instance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following post which has explains how it might be done.

http://designhack.slashlab.net/en/how-to-setup-multiple-wordpress-without-multisite-ft-bitnami/

Make sure to back up important data before you start.

Comment: Sorry, my question focuses around Google Cloud. I understand in general how to create a wordpress site on an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

There is the chance to set up multiple websites using bitnami, but i recommend to kept separate every site to avoid database confusion, and to extend the functionalities of every website.

https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress-multisite

Im using a single VM per domain to avoid confusion with DNS.